# adding CSS to a JavaScript calculation

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add inline CSS to a JS calculation (ex. 3*2*1) to make it red. 
I have already trying a span tag but it just shows the calculation and not the answer. I also tried using an internal style Sheet. How do I do this?
This is the JS fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ytWea/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function volumeFields(){
                document.getElementById("idLengthVolume");
                document.getElementById("idWidthVolume");
                document.getElementById("idHeightVolume");   
                document.getElementById("calcVolume");
            }

            function computeVolume(){
                var x=document.getElementById("idLengthVolume").value;
                var y=document.getElementById("idWidthVolume").value;
                var z=document.getElementById("idHeightVolume").value;
                var sVolume="The volume of your object is " + x * y * z
                document.getElementById("idOutputVolume").innerHTML=sVolume;   
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="volumeFields()">
        Insert the length of your object:<input type="text" size="20" id="idLengthVolume" /> <br/>
        Insert the width of your object:<input type="text" size="20" id="idWidthVolume" /><br/>
        Insert the height of your object:<input type="text" size="20" id="idHeightVolume" />
        <input type="button" style="display:block" onclick="computeVolume()" value="Calculate"  id="calcVolume"/>
        <div id='idOutputVolume'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code. It's not possible to answer your question without code.

Comment: please read the question pretending that you is me (knwoing nothing about your problem)  , and try to answer this question.

Comment: Gus, I added the code that I was working with

Comment: What is the purpose of `volumeFields`? It does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as internal stylesheets, the head node of your html include a style tag and put all of your css in there:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1,p {
                 background-color:red;
                 }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
```

Sorry if this isn't what you are looking for, but it is the best I can do due to the lack of information.

**Edit:**Try this:

```
function computeVolume() {
    var x = document.getElementById("idLengthVolume").length;
    var y = document.getElementById("idWidthVolume").width;
    var z = document.getElementById("idHeightVolume").depth;
    var objvolume = x * y * z;
    var sVolume = "The volume of your object is " + objvolume;
    document.getElementById("idOutputVolume").innerHTML = sVolume;
}
```

Comment: I added the code and the JS fiddle

Comment: @ user2297366, but wheres the CSS

Comment: The css would be in your html file.  I know it wasn't part of the question, but I would reccomend putting your javascript in an external file. It cleans up the code. Css depends on personal taste and I couldn't design your html how you like. I can tell you where to place your css though. I would either put them in the head node as I showed in my answer or inline with your html elements like how you had them in your question.